# DJango - How To pass the full model object as new field in serializer

Tags: python, arrays, django, object, django-rest-framework

I want to pass the full Artist model object to the Serializer so I created a new Field `serializers.SerializerMethodField` and passed Artist object inside it. but I get the error.

```
getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    similar_artists = serializers.SerializerMethodField(Artist.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'artist_name', 'albums', 'similar_artists')
```

I guess I'm doing it totally wrong. so is there any way to pass all values or all Artists in single object with serializer with a manual field.

I want to achieve something like this in serializer.

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "albums": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "album_name": "Fearless (Taylor's Version)"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "album_name": "Reputation"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "album_name": "1989"
            }
        ],
        "artist_name": "Taylor Swift",
        "similar_artists": [
           {
              Artist Object
           }
         ]
 
    },
```

**Model Artist**

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'artist_name', 'albums',)


class ArtistSimilarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    similar_artists = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_similar_artists(self, artist):
        queryset = Artist.objects.all()
        return ArtistSerializer(queryset, many=True).data


    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'artist_name', 'albums', 'similar_artists')
```

Try this